# Offset page number but not the line — fancyhdr package

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using `fancyhdr` package to create a footer. Unfortunately, I cannot offset the page number only but keep the horizontal line going all the way to the margin. I tried using `\fancyfootoffset{-1cm}` but it offsets the entire footer

[image]

EDIT: Here would be my latex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    headheight=27mm,
    footskip=8mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    right=12mm
    }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}% Change page style to fancy
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer

\fancyfoot[L]{some footer text}% \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}% Default \headrulewidth is 0.4pt
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}% Default \footrulewidth is 0pt

\begin{document}

Some text

\setcounter{page}{2}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}

\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfootoffset{-1cm}

\end{document}
```

Could you please help me out? Thanks

Comment: Try `\fancyfoot[R]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{1cm}\thepage}}`. And, by the way `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}` is not necessary, as that is the default.

Comment: Or `\fancyfoot[R]{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thepage}}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo It depends what the desired result is. I interpreted it as the pagenumber sticking out in the margin, i.e. the end of the line being moved to the left, but not  the page number. I now see that it could also be interpreted to shift the page number to the left. `\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\hspace{1cm}}` would then also work.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum - One is left of and one right of the 1cm mark, not that anyone would notice.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, but it is not specified which one is desired.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Yes, the goal is to move just the page number to the left and leave the end of the line in the same spot where it is now (at the margin).